# Skype Personal integration with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, skypedeveloper

It's been weeks of searching everywhere but couldn't find any help and finally i'm posting my query here.

I'm not finding a way to integrate Skype Personal (*Not Skype Business/Lync*) in my c# application. I just want to receive Skype messages on my application. I have tried using Skype4com Library but it has discontinued and does not support the latest Skype and LYNC API also works only with Skype for business and same with Skype Web SDK as it does not work with Skype personal. I also tried the method to fetch the details through Skype local database but latest version of Skype doesn't store anything locally.

**Note: There are still some applications with Skype integration that I know but I don't know how they do that.**

Comment: I remember back in 2014, Skype shutdown its Desktop APIs.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt but there are still some applications interacting with skype. I'm referring https://kb.teramind.co/hc/en-us/articles/1500003350921-User-Guide.